# How to put exception for only string value?

Tags: java, string, exception

I am taking input from user and it should be string only, but code is not working as I expected. Here is my code `

```
while(true){
    try{
      System.out.print("Enter test string");
      str=sc.nextLine();
      break;
    }
    catch(InputMismatchException e) {
     System.out.println("Please enter String value");
     continue;
    }
  }
  System.out.println(str);
`
```

If I am giving integer value than it should ask again but here it is printing integer value.Also no Special character

Comment: A `String` can contain ascii characters that are digits... why would "123" be illegal?

Comment: try with this `str = sc.nextLine();
if (str.matches("\\d")) {
    continue;
} break;`

Comment: The code you provided does never throw an `InputMismatchException`.

Comment: `[teach-me]` When the user types *12345<enter>*, it's a string. It can also be interpreted as integer, floating point value, hex integer and possibly in other ways, but first and foremost it's a string.

Answer (score 1):

If you tried to parse the integer directly, then you'd get a more meaningful exception to catch.

```
String str = "";
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter test string");
        str = sc.nextLine();
        Integer.parseInt(str);
        System.out.println("Please enter String value");
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // You *didn't* get a number; you actually have a String now.
        // You can terminate the loop here.
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

check if string not number like this:

```
while(true){
        try{
            System.out.print("Enter test string");
            str=sc.nextLine();

            if(isNumeric(str)) {
                continue;
            }
            break;
        }
        catch(InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Please enter String value");
            continue;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(str);
}

public static boolean isNumeric(String str)
{
    for (char c : str.toCharArray())
    {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to check if the string is NOT a number, you can try

```
String str = sc.nextLine();
if (StringUtils.isNumeric(str))
    System.out.println(str);
```

but this method will not work if your number has a decimal or something.

check [How to check if a String is numeric in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

for a similar answer

Answer (score -1):

```
str=sc.nextLine();
```

takes everything as a string hence there is no exception. Try using statement like this

```
int num; 
  &
num=sc.nextInt();
```

and you will find that the exception will is caught so there is no problem with the code.

Suppose that user will enter `"This is 1 String"` even though it contains integer but still it is a String. Same applies every time even when user enter `"43728"` it is still considered a String

here is how you can accomplish your goal

```
while(true){
              System.out.print("Enter test string");
              str=sc.nextLine();
              Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d");
              Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
              if (matcher.find()) {
                  //System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
                 continue; 
              }
              break;
          }
```

Comment: Consider not using the name "str" for a variable that is meant to be an int. That is just lying to the reader.

Comment: i tried not to change the syntax for the convenience of questioner. if stackoverflow thinks its bad i'll edit it and never do again

Comment: We all have opinions about code conventions, and they're just that:  opinions.  You should write the clearest code you can.

Comment: That said, one irrefutable *fact* is that using `nextInt` is *not* going to give the OP what they want.  They need to consume the entire line at once, even if this means that they're going to have a string with "d1234" (which would qualify as a "String").

Comment: I understand it will not solve his problem. Here i was only trying to tell him that there is no problem with code the problem is in Logic of code